# Is it possible to embed a Vimeo video in an iOS app using a UIButton?

Tags: ios, video, uibutton, vimeo

Is it possible to embed a Vimeo video in an iOS app using a UIButton instead of doing it using a UIWebView?

My idea is to click an UIButton to play a Vimeo video in-app, without launching Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to start a video by click of a UIButton - yes.

Is it possible to embed a video in UIButton - no. Video still needs to be hosted within a UIWebView.

Hosting UIWebView in an app is not the same as starting Safari. UIWebView is a part of your app, Safari is a whole another app. You have complete control over what's going on inside a UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Vimeo app on the store and an API plus its documentation on Vimeo.com. The last time I checked third parties weren't able and allowed to embed the clips directly in the App since they don't have access to th mp4 files on Vimeos content delivery network.

But Vimeo itself does, so if you know what you're doing you can come up with the idea to monitor Vimeos app network traffic and reverse engineer how they access the mp4s. But before you do that, you probably better contact their support.

Comment: For what I've read, Apple only accepts streaming videos using HTTP Live Streaming protocol instead of embedding them on an UIWebView. Vimeo only brings HLS if you're a Vimeo PRO member (199$/year).

Comment: Where did you get that information? From googling for two seconds it seems that they explicitly do not offer that for any customers (both free and pro): http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:46504 and http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:67118